# How can CodePipeline do migration db to RDS with ECS

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline

I made CodePipeline will deploy container to ECS.
And I`m trying to make migration task via Deploy step in CodePipeline.

I can run one-off task manually from Task Definition.
But CodePipeline cannot run one-off task.

Any idea? I need other services?

Best regards, Takuto.

Answer (score 0):

A common solution for "one off" tasks is to run them as a separate action before you deploy. So, for example you might have a separate CodeBuild action run the migrations first, then run your fleet deployment.

Comment: Hello Tim, Thanks for your answer. I tried it. But never work.